# ionic3 - local notification fire in same time

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I want set a local notification will push at a two different time,but the two notification fire at same time. Here is my code:

```
let three_sec = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3000)
let six_sec= new Date(new Date().getTime() + 6000)
moment(three_sec).add(3, "second")
moment(six_sec).add(6, "second")
this.LocalNotifications.schedule([{
  id: 0,
  text: "3sec",
  trigger: {at: three_sec}
},{
  id: 1,
  text: "6second",
  trigger: {at: six_sec},
}])
```

}

Comment: and why are adding 3 or 6 seconds two times, 1st in date constructor and  2nd in `moment().add()`. Does 2nd one really changes the `three_sec` or it returns `new Date` without modifying the argument.

Comment: directly from the docs : `trigger: {at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600)},` why using moment.js ?

Comment: I checked the value of three_sec and six_sec.The 2nd one is really changes the value

Comment: I use momentjs because i got some function need to edit the time with some timezone.I use the code from the docs.It still fire the notification in same time.